# How to use orbs in Perfect World International?

Tags: perfect-world

Does anybody know how to get dragon orbs and use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dragon Orbs are used in refining and purchased from the cash shop or traded for with other players.** Orb quality can be improved by combining them. The details can be found [on the wiki](http://pwi-wiki.perfectworld.com/index.php/Refining#Refining_With_Dragon_Orbs):

> ### Refining With Dragon Orbs
>
> Dragon orbs are an item that can be bought through the cash shop or from other players. Using these alongside the mirage stones will ensure that your refining never fails.
>
> Note: You must use the dragon orb for the current refine or higher or it will not work.
>
> - Ex. Using a 1* dragon orb when trying to refine to +2 will not have a 100% success rate, you will need to use a 2* dragon orb or above.
> - Ex. If you want to refine a piece of gear to +6 you would need a 1*, 2*, 3*, 4*, 5*, and a 6* orb to get there with a 100% success rate.
>
> Currently the most cost efficient way to make higher grade orbs is to buy the orbs from other players or in the 1* 10 packs from the cash shop. To convert the 1* orbs into higher grade orbs, you need to take them to any Jewelcraftsman NPC, select the 'combine' option, and go to the last tab 'Orb'.
>
> ```
>    1* Orbs Needed for Higher Refines:
>    Orb Wanted  1* Orbs Needed  Total Needed
>    1*          1               1
>    2*          4               5
>    3*          10              15
>    4*          25              40
>    5*          60              100
>    6*          130             230
>    7*          215             445
>    8*          405             850
>    9*          750             1,600
>    10*         1,370           2,970
>    11*         2,525           5,495
>    12*         4,645           10,140
> ```
>
> For +10, +11, and +12 orbs it is much cheaper to utilize the +10 ocean orb which is often on sale in the boutique. Please refer to the section below for details.
>
> After combining the orbs to get to the refine you desire, bring the orbs and the amount of mirages needed to an Elder in any major city.
>
> WARNING: Do NOT place your gear into the gear box and click refine like you normally would. This will NOT use your dragon orb and give you 100% success rate.
>
> To use the dragon orbs you must start with the first refine (usually the 1* orb) and place it into the 'Special Materials' box along with placing your gear into the 'Gear' box. Then it is safe to press refine and your gear will be increased to +1. Repeat what you just did with each orb increasing your refine until you are the refine you wanted to obtain.
>
> Make sure you do not double click the refine button and accidentally refine it once without a dragon orb and lose all your previous refines!
>
> ### Producing dragon orbs
>
> If you are going to manufacture your own dragon orbs, here is a guide to how many you need. For orbs of +10 or higher it is cheaper to utilize a mixture of +1 orbs and +10 ocean orbs which are often on sale in the boutique. The orbs that should be purchased are highlighted...
>
> ```
>    Dragon orbs produced
>        *1**** 2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   *10* 11  12
>    1   *1****
>    2   *4**** 1
>    3   *10*** 2   1
>    4   *25*** 5   2   1
>    5   *60*** 12  5   2   1
>    6   *130** 26  11  4   2   1
>    7   *215** 43  18  7   3   1   1
>    8   *405** 81  34  13  6   2   1   1
>    9   *750** 150 63  24  11  4   2   1   1
>    10                                         *1**
>    11  *1155* 231 97  37  17  6   3   2   1   *1** 1
>    12  *1905* 381 160 61  28  10  5   3   2   *2** 1   1
> ```
>
> Each row describes how to make a dragon orb. (Except that 10* dragon orbs, when they are on sale, are much cheaper to buy than to make.)
>
> So, for example, to make a 3* orb, you can start with 10 one* orbs, and then make 2 two* orbs which will give you the supplies you need to make a three* orb.
>
> If for some reason you want +10,+11 or +12 refines without buying the +10 orbs, you will need to do this instead:
>
> ```
>    +10/11/12 Dragon orbs from +1
>        *1**** 2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
>    10  *1370* 274 115 44  20  7   4   2   1   1
>    11  *2525* 505 212 81  37  13  7   4   2   1   1
>    12  *4645* 929 390 149 68  24  13  7   4   2   1   1
> ```